# TextBlock x:name property not available in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, visual-studio-2017

Can someone explain to my why the name property in the this tag `<Image x:Name="imgCover" Source="{Binding Cover}" Margin="0,0,20,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave"/>` is not available in the code-behind?

As you can see I have two event handlers bound to this tag that I want to use to modify the Image properties with but the name property is not available (IntelliSense or manually).

Of note is that I have another `ListView` control that is setup exacatly the same as this one (except the `<DataTemplate>` tag contains `TextBlock` controls instead of an `Image` control.  It works as expected.

Things I have done based on other post:  Removed and re entered the entire `ListView` tag; rebuild project; restart VS2017.

Here is the tag within the XAML file:

```
<ListView  Grid.Column="1" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQueryResults}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="imgCover" Source="{Binding Cover}" Margin="0,0,20,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave"/>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: You can't get your img by name, because it's id is not unique. It's inside DataTemplate, that's mean you can have many items with this image, so the name will be ignored outside of template. You can use your name just in  DataTemplate's scope.

Comment: `imgCover` is a part of template, there are not directly accessibly from code. you can use `sender` object in event handlers - make a type cast and get an Image

Comment: The question is, why would you want to use name in codebehind?